# Loading angular2 application without systemjs dynamic loader in browser

Tags: angular, systemjs

Is there a way I can load and bootstrap angular2 application without systemjs dynamic loader in browser? I mean I want to load all js files with `<script>` tag or jquery $.loadScript() and then want to bootstrap angular2 app when all scripts loaded.

I am developing an application which will be injected inside another application and I have to load all my js, html, css at a time in the browser. There will be no dynamic loading option due to server security. so I cannot use systemjs dynamic loading and I have to load all html, css, js once and once that are loaded I need to bootstrap the angular2 application in browser.

I gone through all other links and they are all provided how to do with systemjs dynamic loading but I need other way.

Comment: Have you taken a look at WebPack?

Comment: No, as of my understanding webpack is for typescript building and its required while compiling typescript to js files. But I need to stop dynamic loading in the browser which loads js files and then bootstrap angular2 into browser. Is webpack does that in the browser?

Comment: No. SystemJS and Webpack should be mutually exclusive. Neither serves the purpose of compiling TypeScript. Webpack is an alternative to SystemJS. With it you should be able to concatenate your modules into a single JS object file.

Comment: Got it, Let me try that.

Comment: Take a look at the Angular-CLI and test it out. It provides Webpack with a config, and if it looks like it handles your needs either migrate to the CLI or migrate to Webpack.

Comment: Sure @gelliott181, I will look into that and will let you know the result. I am stuck in that application in which I cannot use dynamic loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the angular-cli option works for me. After beta-10 they removed systemjs dynamic loader and creating one js file for libraries (all dependencies like angular, rxjs, etc) and one js file for all project code. So the production build will only contain 2 js file link in your index.html file. No dynamic loading and rest calls to my server for the scripts.

I have created 2 yo generator to scaffold application, one with systemjs dynamic loading and another without systemjs loading in case anyone have the same issue can refer.

**Without systemjs (angular-cli):**

```
npm install -g yo
npm install -g generator-angular2-without-systemjs
yo generator-angular2-without-systemjs
```

**With systemjs dynamic loading:**

```
npm install -g yo
npm install -g generator-angular2-with-systemjs
yo generator-angular2-with-systemjs
```

**problem with Babel::**

Babel does not supports typescript, To use babel, I have to move all my typescript code to js and the syntax is also little different. I did not wont to move away from typescript